# window.pageYOffset is sometimes 0 instead of a valid value

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I'm having a problem where sometimes when my JavaScript in a Web page gets the value of `window.pageYOffset` it is inexplicably 0 even though I know the user is viewing the middle of the document and its value should be huge, like 650000. Note that a huge percentage of the time I get a reasonable value. But sometimes it's zero and sometimes it's a seemingly random small value, like in the 6000 range when I'm expecting 650000.

Rather than post a bunch of code, I'd like to ask some general questions to help me figure out where to begin to look.

This page is being displayed in an iOS `WKWebView` (though this problem can manifest in a similar context in an Android app). JavaScript methods in my app can be invoked in one of several ways:

1. When my app is notified that the page has finished loading (via a delegate method), it invokes a JavaScript method using `evaluateJavaScript` from the Objective-C code.
2. My app can call `evaluateJavaScript` at other times, not just when the page finishes loading.
3. A JavaScript function may be called as the result of a timer firing.
4. A JavaScript function may be called as the result of a scroll event.

I have been operating under the assumption that the JavaScript code on the page is always operating in a single thread. That is, I don't have a situation where a timer firing, a scroll event happening, or even a call from the Objective-C code (using `evaluateJavaScript`) is interrupting anything that might be happening in the JavaScript runtime. So I shouldn't have to worry about interrupting some system-level activity that is modifying `window.pageYOffset` while I'm trying to access it.

So that's my first question: Am I correct that someone outside my code is invoking my JavaScript methods on a single thread and not monkeying with the DOM on another thread?

My second question is related: My code modifies the DOM, adding and removing `div` elements. I've been assuming that those modifications are synchronous -- if I insert an element with `insertAfter` or `insertBefore`, I expect that the child/parent/sibling pointers are accurate upon return, and I assume that I can immediately access things like the `top` and `left` values on some other element and they will have been updated to reflect the inserted/removed element. The point being that I shouldn't have to "wait" for the DOM to "stabilize" after making changes and before checking something like `window.pageYOffset`. Is this correct?

One more clue: To help mitigate this, I have had good luck simply testing `window.pageYOffset` for zero at the top of a function. If it is zero, I call myself back on a timer (with just a 1 msec delay). If I do that long enough, it will eventually be non-zero.

Perhaps after reading all this, none of the detail is relevant and you know the answer to the basic question: Why do I sometimes get an invalid value (usually 0) in `window.pageYOffset` when the same line of code gives a valid value at other times.

Comment: Rather than taking your word for it, how about you post *some* code?

Comment: The problem is that there are about 4000 lines of JavaScript here. My general questions don't really require any code -- are JavaScript calls that come from my iOS app, JavaScript calls that result from a timer firing, JavaScript calls that result from an event handler, and all the system-level DOM code all running on a single thread? And second, after inserting or removing an element, is it reasonable to expect that `window.pageYOffset` and any other size/position values have been updated to reflect the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that there appears to be a period of time between when I give the `WKWebView` a new HTML string to render and when it tells me that it is done loading the page that the existing page is still active. During this time, timers continue to fire, but some `document` and `window` properties will not be valid.

Because of the difficulty of debugging JavaScript running in this environment, I was tricking myself into thinking "eventually `pageYOffset` becomes valid" when in fact what I was seeing was that the new page eventually finished loading, and it was this new page that was generating valid calls to my timer functions.

In my particular case (may not work for everyone) I am able to detect the value of `window.pageYOffset` at the top of my timer function and if it is 0, call myself back after a brief delay. This allows me to handle the case where, for some reason, `window.pageYOffset` is just not yet valid (my test will eventually pass and my timer function will continue as usual) and the case where everything is in the process of being thrown away in favor of the new page (in which case the timer will not fire because the page goes away).